# how to create resume and pause in one fragment to another when that one fragment ins running and restore it

Tags: android, fragment-lifecycle

i have one activity with 3 fragment using bottom navigation if i start my score_fragment inside has operation using button to textview in activity if i pause it and return with resume (draft )
Activity

```
public class FirstPlayedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    public static int i,j;
    int Wickets = 0,team_wicket = 0;
    public static int Score_run = 0,team_score = 0;
    public static int Over= MatchActivity.Over;
    public static boolean  allout = false;
    public static boolean end_over = false;

    public static String[][] Overs = new String[Over][20] ;
     private ViewPager2 viewPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
     private FragmentStateAdapter pagerAdapter;
     View view;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_played);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.Score);



    }

    Score_Fragment ScoreFragment = new Score_Fragment();
    Analysis_Fragment AnalysisFragment = new Analysis_Fragment();
    Summary_Fragment SummaryFragment = new Summary_Fragment();

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Score:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.flFragment,  ScoreFragment).addToBackStack(null)
                        .show(ScoreFragment)
                        .hide(SummaryFragment)
                        .hide(AnalysisFragment)
                        .commit();

                return true;

            case R.id.Summary:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.flFragment, SummaryFragment).addToBackStack(null)
                        .hide(ScoreFragment)
                        .hide(AnalysisFragment)
                        .show(SummaryFragment)
                        .commit();

                return true;

            case R.id.Analysis:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.flFragment, AnalysisFragment).addToBackStack(null)
                        .hide(ScoreFragment)
                        .hide(SummaryFragment)
                        .show(AnalysisFragment)
                        .commit();

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

score_fragment

```
public class Score_Fragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    public static int Score_run = 0,team_score = 0 ,this_over = 0;
    public static double Run_rate = 0.0;
    public static int i,j,k;
    public static int Wickets = 0,team_wicket = 0;
    public static int Over= MatchActivity.Over;
    public static boolean  allout = false;
    public static boolean end_innings = false;

    public static String[][] Overs = new String[Over][20] ;
    public static  boolean undoState = false;
    private boolean isViewShown = false;

    public Score_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static Score_Fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Score_Fragment fragment = new Score_Fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score_, container, false);
         TextView  runs = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.runs) ;
         TextView no_of_wickets = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.no_of_wicket) ;
         TextView balls = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.over_number);
         TextView run_rate = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.run_rate);

        ImageButton wicket = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.wicket);
        ImageButton dot = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.dot);
        ImageButton one = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.one);
        ImageButton two = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.two);
        ImageButton three = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.three);
        ImageButton four = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.four);
        ImageButton six = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.six);
        ImageButton wide = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.wide);
        ImageButton wide1 = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.wide_one);
        ImageButton wide2 = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.wide_two);
        ImageButton wide3 = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.wide_three);
        ImageButton wide4 = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.wide_four);
        ImageButton noball = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.noball);
        ImageButton noball_one = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.noball_one);
        ImageButton noball_two = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.noball_two);
        ImageButton noball_three = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.noball_three);
        ImageButton noball_four = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.noball_four);
        ImageButton noball_six = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.noball_six);
        ImageButton legbyes_one = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.lb1);
        ImageButton legbyes_two = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.lb2);
        ImageButton legbyes_three = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.lb3);
        ImageButton legbyes_four = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.lb4);
        ImageButton byes_one = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        ImageButton byes_two = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.b2);
        ImageButton byes_three = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.b3);
        ImageButton byes_four = (ImageButton)View.findViewById(R.id.b4);
        LinearLayout this_over_display = (LinearLayout)View.findViewById(R.id.thisover_display);

        i =0;
        j=0;
        k = 0;


            wicket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Wickets = 1;
                        team_wicket += 1;
                        if (team_wicket <= 10) {
                            if (team_wicket == 10) {
                                allout = true;
                            }
                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wicket);
                            Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                            int disp = Integer.parseInt(no_of_wickets.getText() + "");
                            no_of_wickets.setText(Wickets + disp + "");
                            Overs[i][k] = "W";
                            j++;
                            k++;
                            if (j == 6) {
                                j = 0;
                                k = 0;
                                i++;
                                Run_rate = team_score/i;
                                this_over = 0;


                                balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                            } else {
                                balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                            }

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " All OUT !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                }


            });
            dot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 0;
                        team_score += 0;
                        this_over += 0;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "0";
                        k++;
                        j++;
                        if (j == 6) {
                            j = 0;
                            k = 0;
                            i++;
                            Run_rate = team_score/i;
                            this_over = 0;



                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        } else {
                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        }


                    }

                }
            });

            one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 1;
                        team_score += 1;
                        this_over += 1;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "1";
                        k++;
                        j++;
                        if (j == 6) {
                            j = 0;
                            k = 0;
                            i++;
                            Run_rate = team_score/i;
                            this_over = 0;


                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        } else {
                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        }


                    }

                }
            });

            two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 2;
                        team_score += 2;
                        this_over += 2;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "2";
                        k++;
                        j++;
                        if (j == 6) {
                            j = 0;
                            k = 0;
                            i++;
                            Run_rate = team_score/i;
                            this_over = 0;


                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        } else {
                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        }


                    }

                }
            });

            three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 3;
                        team_score += 3;
                        this_over += 3;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "3";
                        k++;
                        j++;
                        if (j == 6) {
                            j = 0;
                            k = 0;
                            i++;
                            Run_rate = team_score/i;
                            this_over = 0;


                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        } else {
                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        }


                    }

                }
            });

            four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 4;
                        team_score += 4;
                        this_over += 4;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "4";
                        k++;
                        j++;
                        if (j == 6) {
                            j = 0;
                            k = 0;
                            i++;
                            Run_rate = team_score/i;
                            this_over = 0;


                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        } else {
                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        }

                    }

                }
            });

            six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 6;
                        team_score += 6;
                        this_over += 6;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.six);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "6";
                        k++;
                        j++;
                        if (j == 6) {
                            j = 0;
                            k = 0;
                            i++;
                            Run_rate = team_score/i;
                            this_over = 0;


                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        } else {
                            balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        }

                    }


                }
            });
            wide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 1;
                        team_score += 1;
                        this_over += 1;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wide);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "0Wd";
                        k++;


                    }


                }
            });

            wide1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 2;
                        team_score += 2;
                        this_over += 2;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wide1);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "1Wd";
                        k++;

                    }


                }
            });

            wide2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 3;
                        team_score += 3;
                        this_over += 3;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wide2);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "2Wd";
                        k++;


                    }


                }
            });
            wide3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (i == Over) {
                        end_innings = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " END OF THE INNINGS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Score_run = 4;
                        team_score += 4;
                        this_over += 4;
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wide3);
                        Addview(imageView, 75, 75);
                        int disp = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText() + "");
                        runs.setText(Score_run + disp + "");
                        balls.setText(i + "." + j + "");
                        Overs[i][k] = "3Wd";
                        k++;

                    }


                }
            });

          






        return View;
    }



   

    public void Addview(ImageView imageView, int width, int height) {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
        LinearLayout this_over_display = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.thisover_display);
        // setting the margin in linearlayout
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

        // adding the image in layout
        this_over_display.addView(imageView);
        getView().findViewById(R.id.ball).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ((HorizontalScrollView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ball)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

summary_fragment

```
public class Summary_Fragment extends Fragment {

   int runs_T = Score_Fragment.team_score;
   int wicket_T = Score_Fragment.team_wicket;
   public static float Run_rate ;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public Summary_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

     public static Summary_Fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Summary_Fragment fragment = new Summary_Fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop: ");
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary_, container, false);


        return  view;
    }
}
```

how to pause my fragment to current state of fragments i need solution for this